# ng-model in a md-select doesn't update selected value

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using a md-select:

```
<label>Type</label>
<md-select ng-model="selected_data_type">
    <md-option ng-repeat="data_type in data_types" value="{{data_type.name}}">{{data_type.name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

That is preloaded with data using:

```
for (let type of getData())
   $scope.data_types.push({ name: type });
```

And also setting a default value after the data has been loaded:

```
$scope.selected_data_type = data.type
```

So now I got a md-select with some items and a selected item as *default*, but when changing selected item to any other than the *default* and pressing an event button, that triggers `console.log($scope.selected_data_type);` gives the *default* selected value. Why is that?

Comment: Any Fiddle available ?

Comment: @AdnanUmer https://codepen.io/President_Camacho/pen/RRvvNN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you provide is a bit confusing. In your question you have (1)

```
value="{{data_type.name}}"
```

which is correct. While in your CodePen example you have

```
ng-value="{{data_type.name}}"
```

which is incorrect. It should be (2)

```
ng-value="data_type.name"
```

Your CodePen works with both (1) and (2), as you can see in the console.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/JKxVOv?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `value` use `ng-value`. From the [official documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect)

```
<md-input-container>
  <md-select ng-model="someModel" placeholder="Select a state">
    <md-option ng-value="opt" ng-repeat="opt in neighborhoods2">{{ opt }}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: using ng-value doesn't change anything except for that I don't got a default set value now.